# Fragment doesn't execute AsyncTask on startup

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

When my app starts up, it replaces layout with fragment, that needs AsyncTask to load correctly. When I load this fragment from navigation drawer, everything works fine, but wen it loads on app startup, AsyncTask doesn't execute. How can i fix this?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    fragmentClass = NewsFragment.class;
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutForFragments, fragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Wybory elementów w navigationdrawer
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_news) {
        fragmentClass = NewsFragment.class;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
        fragmentClass = MapFragment.class;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_buildings) {
        fragmentClass = BuildingsFragment.class;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        fragmentClass = MapFragment.class;


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_info) {
        fragmentClass = AppInfoFragment.class;


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_bugreport) {
        fragmentClass = ContactFragment.class;

    }


    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayoutForFragments, fragment).commit();


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Fragment that loads on startup:

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

public static ArrayList <ParsedWebData> list = new ArrayList<ParsedWebData>();



public NewsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static NewsFragment newInstance(Context context) {
    NewsFragment fragment = new NewsFragment();

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Start AsyncTask w momencie ładowania fragmentu

    AsyncXMLParser parser = new AsyncXMLParser();
    parser.execute();


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewNews);

    CustomListViewAdapter customListViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getContext(), R.id.listViewNews, list);
    listView.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            ParsedWebData singleData = list.get(position);
            String url = singleData.getUrl();

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(browserIntent);


        }
    });




    return view;
}

}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncXMLParser extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, ArrayList<ParsedWebData>> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ParsedWebData> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<ParsedWebData> list = new ArrayList<ParsedWebData>();

        try {

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // We will get the XML from an input stream
            InputStream input = new URL("linkhere").openStream();
            xpp.setInput(input, "UTF_8");

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            String text = null;
            ParsedWebData data = new ParsedWebData();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = xpp.getName();

                switch (eventType) {

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                            data = new ParsedWebData();
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = xpp.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            // add employee object to list
                            list.add(data);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            data.title = text;
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                            data.url = text;
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                            text = Jsoup.parse(text).text();
                            data.description = text;
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();



            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NewsFragment.list = list;

        return list;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList <ParsedWebData> result) {

    }

}
```

I tried to find the reason myself, and tried to execute AsyncTask manually in MainActivity, but it didn't help. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is, that the AsyncTask (thread) finishes after your OnCreateView runs, so you don't see your data.
What you could do, is move the line of code `NewsFragment.list = list;` from `doInBackground()`, to `onPostExecute()`, and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after that. But the issue is that in your design you have no access to listView adapter in AsyncTask
In addition, having the list as a static variable in the Fragment, so that you can access it from the AsyncTask is very bad programming design.
You should remove the static list variable, and should redesign your AsyncTask, that you pass the listView to the constructor (you will have to move it from onCreate to onCreateView), and assign the listView to a member in the AsyncTask. Then in onPostExecute set the adapter (not in onCreateView)

```
public class AsyncXMLParser extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, ArrayList<ParsedWebData>> { 

    CustomListViewAdapter _adapter;

    Public AsyncXMLParser(CustomListViewAdapter adapter) {
       _adapter = adapter;
    }

   ...

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList <ParsedWebData> result) { 
        CustomListViewAdapter customListViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getContext(), R.id.listViewNews, result);
        listView.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter); 
    // Or, depending on design
        _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This way, the list is not static variable (you can remove code from the fragment), and the listView is filled only after the AsyncTask is finished. If you later need access to the actual list data, you can get it from the Adapter.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do this, since my list is populated from multiple sources, not only AsyncTask

Comment: So just pass the adapter to the AsyncTask and call `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Can You show me how to do this? I can't find a way to pass my adapter.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how, but you will have to adjust the code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the reason to why Asynctask isnt being executed but depending on how much background work you want to do, you might not want to use 
Asynctask. Asynctask should only be used to do operations that take a small amount of time(at most seconds) since its lifetime is tied to the lifetime of a ui compoment. The issue here could very well be that you're killing the asynctask because its connected to the ui.

I would recommend you to use an intentservice. They are really easy to use and can run as long as you like in the background. Since u can't seem to find the issue with Asynctask in this case you would probably save time by using intentservices instead. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Parsing operation doesn't take more than a second in my case, xml file I'm parsing is about 30kb in size. I don't think that AsyncTask is a problem here, I'm guessing that there's something wrong when the fragment launches.

Comment: does the fragment launch from oncreate?

Comment: What i was trying to get at earlier was that perhaps your doing something to the fragment which causes asynctask to interrupt. for example these lines might mess with your fragment :  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutForFragments, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: Basically, you can never guarantee execution with asynctask. So if you need to guarantee that the task will be done you should use a different approach-